# parsing key/value pairs from string

Tags: javascript, regex, scala

I'm parsing the body text from incoming emails, looking for key/value pairs.

**Example Email Body**
First Name: John
Last Name:Smith
Email : john@example.com
Comments = Just a test comment that
may span multiple lines.

I tried using a RegEx `([\w\d\s]+)\s?[=|:]\s?(.+)` in multiline mode. This works for most emails, but fails when there's a line break that should be part of the **value**. I don't know enough about RegEx to go any further.

I have another parser that goes line-by-line looking for the key/value pairs and simply folds a line into the last matched value if a key/value pair is NOT found. It's implemented in Scala.

```
val lines = text.split("\\r?\\n").toList
var lastLabelled: Int = -1
val linesBuffer = mutable.ListBuffer[(String, String)]()

// only parse lines until the first blank line
// null_? method is checks for empty strings and nulls
lines.takeWhile(!_.null_?).foreach(line => {
  line.splitAt(delimiter) match {
    case Nil if line.nonEmpty => {
      val l = linesBuffer(lastLabelled)
      linesBuffer(lastLabelled) = (l._1, l._2 + "\n" + line)
    }
    case pair :: Nil => {
      lastLabelled = linesBuffer.length
      linesBuffer += pair
    }
    case _ => // skip this line
  }
})
```

I'm trying to use RegEx so that I can save the parser to the db and change it on a per-sender basis at runtime (implement different parsers for different senders).

Can my RegEx be modified to match values that contain newlines?
Do I need to just forget about using RegEx and use some JavaScript? I already have a JavaScript parser that lets me store the JS in the DB and essentially do everything that I ***want*** to do with the RegEx parser.

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: You'r saying I should use something like ANTLR (a parser generator)? I'm really looking for a quick-n-dirty fix to the above problem without having to bring in a whole new toolset.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work...

```
((.+?)((\s*)(:|=)(\s*)))(((.|\n)(?!((.+?)(:|=))))+)
```

...as tested here http://regexpal.com/.  If you loop through the matches you should be able to pull out the key and value.